# Psychopy-moving textstim with endpoint

Tags: python, text, psychopy

I am working in psychopy and I would like to have a text stim slide from one position to another over the course of several frames. I have tried the [frameN,0] in the position section for the text stim but I am unsure how to set an endpoint (time/ frames and position).Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Start by calculating the step size for each frame. It's just the difference between the end and start coordinates divided by the number of frames. `numpy` arrays comes in handy here although you could do it in base python as well:

```py
import numpy as np
start_pos = np.array([-0.5, 0])  # [x, y] norm units in this case where TextSTim inherits 'units' from the Window, which has 'norm' as default.
end_pos = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
animation_duration = 30  # duration in number of frames
step_pos = (end_pos - start_pos)/animation_duration
```

Then put it to use:

```py
# Set up psychopy stuff
from psychopy import visual
win = visual.Window()
text = visual.TextStim(win, text='Watch me slide!')

# Animate
text.pos = start_pos
for i in range(animation_duration):
    text.pos += step_pos  # add to existing value. This is shorthand for writing: text_pos = text.pos + step_pos
    text.draw()
    win.flip()
```